# Is there an alternative way to install illustrator scripts on Windows?

Tags: script, windows-11, administrator, adobe-illustrator

I have a work computer that is controlled by an admin so I can't copy files into the program folder without calling them. I have tens of scripts to set up and copy into this folder which will require several calls and tedium!

Is there a way to change where Illustrator looks for scripts or an alternative way to copy the file into the folder that won't require admin rights?

Comment: Try perhaps [Script Bay](http://in-tools.com/article/script-bay/script-panel-replacement-for-the-entire-creative-suite/) (if it still works).